# Sharing third party libraries using Module Federation

Tags: javascript, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

We have micro frontend apps using webpack module federation. our architecture looks like this:
common app: hosts all the shared custom components.
all other apps: depend on the common app to get and use the custom components

I want to also make sure that common and other apps use the same third party libraries so that whenever there's an update we only update the common app without touching other apps.
is it a good idea to export these libraries from the common app and make other apps import them through remoteEntry or are there better solutions?